# TypeScript JQuery UI Typed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, typescript, phpstorm

I might be going crazy, but I got the jQuery UI definition file for Typescript from [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped). However, when I open it up in the latest version of PHPStorm (6.0.3), I get a whole slew of errors showing up.

Then, when I run the TypeScript compiler to try to compile a file that uses it, it seemingly ignores the definition file entirely. I made an obvious error in the definition file just to test the compilers response (removed a { from a block), and it acted the same. So, I imagine PHPStorm is seeing errors that the TypeScript compiler is also seeing, thus it doesn't work.

I couldn't find any type of version requirements on the Definitely Typed file either, so I'm not sure:

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there actually a bug?
- What version of the TypeScript compiler should I be using?
- If PHPStorm is on an outdated version, how can I update it?

Thanks.

Comment: For typescript 0.9.1 support http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+7+EAP

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to PHPStorm using version 0.8 rather than 0.9 - so for example it expects bool where boolean is actually the type name now.

If you look back through the version history on Definitely Typed you should be able to grab an older version with bool types while you wait for an update from JetBrains.

Answer (score 0):

- TypeScript compiler ignoring the d.ts file:

do you mean that no errors are reported when compiling 'broken' d.ts file like
`'tsc.cmd --sourcemap jquery.d.ts'`?

This shouldn't happen... If you compile not the d.ts file, but some other file that uses it, make sure that d.ts is correcly referenced - like

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
```

- Compiler version should match the version of code you are trying to compile. If you are using the latest version of Definitely Typed, make sure to update your TS compiler to 0.9.1
- PHPStorm 6.* doesn't support TypeScript 0.9.*. Please try the most recent WebStorm 7 EAP (like it's mentioned in the comment above)

Comment: It ignores the jquery UI d.ts, and I've double-triple checked the reference path. I don't get errors when compiling the other file.